# OpenSeaMap tiles not getting loaded in R

Tags: r, leaflet, openseamap

I am trying to load `OpenSeaMap` as a provider tile in `leaflet` in `R`.

```
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenSeaMap) %>% addMarkers(lng = df$Lon,
                                        lat=df$Lat,
                                        label=lapply(labs2, HTML))
```

However, the tiles are not getting loaded and I get an empty map. No errors, just an empty map with no tiles and my markers correctly plotted. Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, through some trial and error, I think I've made it to work. I just added the default `addTiles()` before the `addProviderTiles()`. That seems to work, though I find it a bit strange.

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenSeaMap) %>% addMarkers(lng = df$Lon,
                                        lat=df$Lat,
                                        label=lapply(labs2, HTML))
```